# ASP.NET Core validation: switch off server validation for some properties dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-validation

Is there a way to switch off validation of some model properties based on the bound model value.
Example:

```
public class ContactModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ContactType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

This is some view model, which should retrieve the name of the person, and either his Phone or Email. If user select one of these, it should validate only the selected one. But when Phone is selected, and `Email` is empty, the `ModelState.IsValid == false` and vice versa.

I have tried to hook into the validation process (custom `ValidationAttribute`, `IValidatableObject`) but with no success, as the ValidationContext doesn't provide any useful context - I need to access the `ContactType` value when validating `Phone/Email`. I have even tried to create custom binder, but supressing validation in that stage doesn't provide intended results as it only sets the state of validation to Unvalidated, which is considered as `ModelState.IsValid`.

Only solution I have found so far is to create `ActionFilter/PageFilter` which will find if there is any model of `ContactModel` type, and remove the validation errors for unused fields from ModelState. But I don't feel comfortable with such solution (doesn't seems right to me).
Have any ideas?

Comment: Any update? Does my reply help you?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I suggest you could consider using custom CustomModelValidator and custom ModelValidator to achieve your requirement.

By using this, we could get the whole model by using its container value.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

CustomModelValidatorProvider class:

```
    public void CreateValidators(ModelValidatorProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context.ModelMetadata.ContainerType == typeof(ContactModel))
        {
            context.Results.Add(new ValidatorItem
            {
                Validator = new ContactModelValidator(),
                IsReusable = true
            });
        }
    }

    public class ContactModelValidator : IModelValidator
    {
        private static readonly object _emptyValidationContextInstance = new object();
        public IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(ModelValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var validationResults = new List<ModelValidationResult>();


            if (validationContext.ModelMetadata.Name == "Name" && validationContext.Model == null)
            {
                var validationResult = new ModelValidationResult("", "Name is required");

                validationResults.Add(validationResult);

            }
            if (validationContext.ModelMetadata.Name == "ContactType" && validationContext.Model == null)
            {
                var validationResult = new ModelValidationResult("", "ContactType is required");

                validationResults.Add(validationResult);
            }


            if (validationContext.ModelMetadata.Name == "ContactType" && validationContext.Model == null)
            {
                var validationResult = new ModelValidationResult("", "ContactType is required");

                validationResults.Add(validationResult);
            }

            if (validationContext.ModelMetadata.Name == "Phone" || validationContext.ModelMetadata.Name == "Email")
            {
                if (((ContactModel)validationContext.Container).Phone == null && ((ContactModel)validationContext.Container).Email == null)
                {
                    var validationResult = new ModelValidationResult("", "Phone or Email is required");

                    validationResults.Add(validationResult);
                }
            }

       



            return validationResults;
        }
    }
```

Then add it into startup.cs ConfigureServices method:

```
        services.AddControllers(options=> {
            options.ModelValidatorProviders.Add(new CustomModelValidatorProvider()); 
        });
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Although it works, I cannot accept it as an answer. The same as you have described may be done much easier by implementing `IValidatableObject` in `ContactModel` and checking for real values of the model. But it is my fault - in pursuit to be as simple as possible I have selected simple example. In fact my model has some lists and generic argument, which makes this method useless. I had to find different way - during custom model binding (which I have to do anyway) I manipulate the `ValidationStateEntry` which disable validation for selected part of submodel. +1 anyway.